# Django Rest Framework : null value in column "user_id" of relation "posts_post" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, api, rest

I am getting this error:
IntegrityError at /myapi/posts/
null value in column "user_id" of relation "posts_post" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (18, Osama's Post, This is osama's post, 2023-05-14 09:32:06.191629+00, #123, null)
Basically I am working on a blog.
I have created two APIs one is of user and another is post.
But in when I try to insert a new blog post I get this eroor .
Please help me to resolve this.

My serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Post #post imported from models 
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source = 'user.username') 
    #the username will be current authorized user i,e user.username
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'body', 'created', 'user', 'hashtags')
```

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView 
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import permissions
from .models import Post
from .serializers import PostSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# 1: Get list of all posts 

class PostListAPIView(APIView):  #Base class = APIView 
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated] #only authorized users can access this view

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs): #Get all posts
        posts = Post.objects.all() #Fetch all objects of post
        serializer = PostSerializer(posts, many = True) #serialize the data
        return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK) #return serialized data

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {
            'user': request.user.id,
            'title': request.data.get('title'),
            'body': request.data.get('body'),
            'hashtags': request.data.get('hashtags')
        }
        serializer = PostSerializer(data = data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)



class PostDetailAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Post.objects.get(pk = pk)
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        post = self.get_object(pk)
        if post is None:
            return Response({'error': 'Post not found'}, status = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        serializer = PostSerializer(post)
        return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def put(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        post = self.get_object(pk)
        if post is None:
            return Response({'error': 'Post not found'}, status = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        data = {
            'user': request.user.id,
            'title': request.data.get('title'),
            'body': request.data.get('body'),
            'hashtags':request.data.get('hashtags')
        }
        serializer = PostSerializer(post, data = data, partial = True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            if post.user.id == request.user.id:
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
            return Response({"error": "You are not authorized to edit this post"}, status = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        post = self.get_object(pk)
        if post is None:
            return Response({'error': 'Post not found'}, status = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        if post.user.id == request.user.id:
            post.delete()
            return Response({"res": "Object deleted!"}, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response({"error": "You are not authorized to delete this post"}, status = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
    
class UserPostAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, username, *args, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.filter(username = username).first()
        if user is None:
            return Response({'error': 'User not found'}, status = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        posts = Post.objects.filter(user = user)
        serializer = PostSerializer(posts, many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

My urls.py:

```
    from django.urls import path
    from .views import PostListAPIView, PostDetailAPIView, UserPostAPIView
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', PostListAPIView.as_view()),
        path('<int:pk>/', PostDetailAPIView.as_view()),
        path('<username>/', UserPostAPIView.as_view())
    ]

My models.py

from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model): #Model for post
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE) #FK reference to default user model
    # on_delete = models.CASCADE means if user is deleted , post will be deleted
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    hashtags = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    #name the post object with the title
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs = {'pk': self.pk})
    #generate url based on primary key ,
```